# Google map latLngBounds

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps

I am new in android, I am trying clean a map from polygons which are not viewed on one. I decided to do it in Thread. But when i try to call contains method it throws an exeption "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread"

```
 Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (mPolygones == null || mPolygones.isEmpty())
                    continue;
                synchronized (mPolygones) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mPolygones.size(); i++) {
                        Polygon polygon = mPolygones.get(i);
                        if (mLatLngBounds.contains(polygon.getPoints().get(0))) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("polygon");
                            intent.putExtra("index", i);
                            mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
});
```

I get mLatLngBounds from google map in OnCameraMoveListener callback. Is there any way to do this? I'll be appreciated for all advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was in polygon. I tried to get points from polygon  out of UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this in a separate thread at all? Just run this code in the onCameraIdle listener and you'll be fine. (You don't need to run it for every camera movement.)

Comment: i'll try to describe my task. I receive coordinate from out gps module. Frequency from 2 to 10 Hz. I have to process this coordinate and get to 2 more parallel cordinates using SphericalUtils.computeOffset(). When i receive next, i do same. And then i have to add polygone through processed coordinates. It turns out a lot polygones and map stucks. My decision is set visobility false for each polygone which leaves from visible are of a map. Service gives to activity data and another thread should makes polygones unvisible. I

Comment: In case of my question truble was in polygone.getPoints(). I can't do it from outside UI thread